# What does it mean to put a dot in a Python class argument?

Tags: python, rpc

In Python, I saw a class definition as the following:

```
from protorpc import messages

# Create the request string containing the user's name
class HelloRequest(messages.Message):
    my_name = messages.StringField(1, required=True)
```

What does `messages.Message` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from protorpc import messages
class HelloRequest(messages.Message):
```

Is just another way of spelling:

```
from protorpc.messages import Message
class HelloRequest(Message):
```

Or even...

```
import protorpc
class HelloRequest(protorpc.messages.Message):
```

That is, `HelloRequest` derives from the `Message` `class` in the `messages` *submodule* of the `protorpc` [package](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: I know inheritance but this the first time to see this style. I really like python. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically, HelloRequest comes from the a class named Message in the messages submodule of a specific group named protorpc. What your calling an argument is not an argument. It simply says that HelloRequest is using messages.Message as its start class.