# what does . do in python/sage?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm reading a portion of code and would like to know what P.set_objective(obj)
does  and the P.solve  etc

```
def solve(G, P, x, obj):
P.set_objective(obj)
done=False
precision=11
while not done:
    s=P.solve()
    x_star = P.get_values(x)
    H = G.copy()
    for (u,v,w) in H.edges():
        H.set_edge_label(u,v, w - x_star[u] - x_star[v])
    M_H = H.matching(use_edge_labels=True)

    nu_H = -1*sum(w for (u,v,w) in M_H)
    if round(nu_H-x_star['epsilon'],precision) >= 0:
        done=True
        return P
    else:
        P.add_constraint(sum(x[u] + x[v] - G.edge_label(u,v) for (u,v,w) in M_H) - x['epsilon'] >=0)
return P
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean to put a dot in a Python class argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20933050/what-does-it-mean-to-put-a-dot-in-a-python-class-argument)

Answer (score 1):

`.` is a syntactic notation that lets you access the attributes of an object. This is a general concept for python and many other programming languages.

In `p.set_objective()`; A function, `set_objective` that is bound on the object p is called.

An object (typically instance of a class) can also have attributes that can be accessed using this notation. 
It can also be used to access constants in a module.

Some popular examples could be,

```
a = [1,2,3] # a is a list, an extension of object.
print(a.length) # accessing a function/method
print(a.length()) # evaluating the function.

import string #string is a module
print(string.digits) # a constant in module
```

Answer (score 0):

The "." is the syntax you use to reference a method or attribute of an object.

When you do `P.solve()`, that means that `P` is an object, and `solve` is a method on that object. `P.solve()` calls that method.